# Check if array contains?

Tags: javascript

Write a function that receives an array of foods and checks if it contains the values "pizza" and "bacon". If either of those values is missing, add it to the array.

```js
var foods1 = [ "cookies", "steak" ];
var foods2 = [ "pizza", "salad" ];
var foods3 = [ "pizza", "salad" , "bacon", "chili" ];

function addFoods(array){
    if( !== 'pizza' &&  !== 'bacon'){ // if it's good till here what do i put inside IF
        array.push('pizza');
        array.push('bacon');
    }
    
}

addFoods(foods1);
```

Comment: Please, try to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: Is this a question, or a challenge?

Comment: I think i can do it but i dont know how to check if contains pizza or bacon

Comment: you can try indexOf for arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `indexOf` to check to see if either food is in the array and add it if it is not:

```
function addFoods(array){
  if (array.indexOf('pizza') === -1) array.push('pizza');
  if (array.indexOf('bacon') === -1) array.push('bacon');
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lpbk6uv8/)